# No line number shown for run-time error from Python module

Tags: python, numbers, runtime-error, line, traceback

Most Python errors produce traceback showing the line number of the offending statement. But for some reason some run-time errors do not.

For instance, running "python -m mymodule.py" on a module containing just the two lines:

```
args = {}
if len(args > 2): print("this is a run-time error. Should be: len(args) > 2")
```

fails with:

```
c:\python34\python.exe: Error while finding spec for 'mymodule.py' (<class 'TypeError'>: unorderable types: dict() > int())
```

This sample of code was from a much larger module which failed and, having no line number made it hard to find the coding error.

Comment: You could always print things to see how far the code gets before it fails. I know you can't all the time but for a one off error it's useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use -m, python searches sys.path for the module, and it's not finding the file you specified. This is because the path doesn't (and for reasons of stability and security normally shouldn't) include the current working directory.

Since the error is produced at the command line rather than inside your file, there is no line number for the error.

Finally, to fix the problem, type

```
python -m ./mymodule
```

This fixes two problems from your command line:

1. The .py extension is omitted when doing a module import.
2. You need to explicitly add the path in order to import this module (or move it into a directory in sys.path).

Comment: Many thanks - that was the problem. Leaving off the .py gave me the proper trace (and I didn't need ./ - just "python -m mymodule").

Answer (score 1):

You execute:

```
python -m mymodule.py
```

Try this instead:

```
python mymodule.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Which python version are you using? Python 2.7 shows the error:

```
PATH>python -m scrap
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File “C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py”, line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    “__main_J, fname, loader, pkg_name)
    File “C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py”, line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
    File “PATH\scrap.py”, line 2, in <module>
        if len(args > 2): print(”this is a run-time error. Should be: len(args) > 2’
    )
    TypeError: object of type ‘bool’ has no len()
```